# Spark/Scala: Remove some component from a DataFrame with Array typed column

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

The title may not be very clear. Let me explain what I want to achieve with an example.
Starting with a DataFrame as following:

```
val df = Seq((1, "CS", 0, (0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)), 
             (4, "Ed", 0, (0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6)),
             (7, "CS", 0, (0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7)),
             (101, "CS", 1, (0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8)),
             (5, "CS", 1, (0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9)))
             .toDF("id", "dept", "test", "array")
+---+----+----+--------------------+
| id|dept|test|               array|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
```

I want to remove/drop some elements of the array column according to the information in id, dept and test column. Specifically, the 4 elements in each array correspond to the four id that is in CS dept, and the number is generated with ascend id order (meaning 1, 5, 7, 101). Now I want remove the elements in each array that corresponds to the ids that have test column as 1. In this example, the 2nd and 4th elements will be removed and the end result will look like this:

```
+---+----+----+----------+
| id|dept|test|     array|
+---+----+----+----------+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.4]|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.3]|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.4]|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.3]|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.6]|
+---+----+----+----------+
```

In order to avoid collecting all the results and do the manipulation in Scala. I would like to keep the operation in Spark DataFrame if possible. My thought to tackle this problem includes Two steps:

1. Figure out the Index of array elements that need to be removed
2. Apply the remove/drop operation

So far, I think I have figured out step 1 as following:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    val w = Window.partitionBy("dept").orderBy("id")
    val studentIdIdx = df.select("id", "dept")
      .withColumn("Index", row_number().over(w))
      .where("dept = 'CS'").drop("dept")
    studentIdIdx.show()
    +---+-----+
    | id|Index|
    +---+-----+
    |  1|    1|
    |  5|    2|
    |  7|    3|
    |101|    4|
    +---+-----+
    val testIds = df.where("test = 1")
      .select($"id".as("test_id"))
    val testMask = studentIdIdx
      .join(testIds, studentIdIdx("id") === testIds("test_id"))
      .drop("id","test_id")
    testMask.show()
    +-----+
    |Index|
    +-----+
    |    2|
    |    4|
    +-----+
```

So my two related questions are:

1. How to apply the remove/drop function to each array in each row with the Index? (I am open to suggestion for a better way to figure the Index as well)
2. The real final DataFrame that I want should remove some more element on top of the above result. Specifically, for test=0 & dept=CS, it should remove the array element that correspond to the Index of the id. In this example, the 1st element in the row with id=1 and the 3rd element (original index before any removal) in the row with id=7 should be removed, and the real final result is:

   ```
   +---+----+----+----------+    
   | id|dept|test|     array|
   +---+----+----+----------+
   |  1|  CS|   0|[0.4]     |
   |  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.3]|
   |  7|  CS|   0|[0.2]     |
   |101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.3]|
   |  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.6]|
   +---+----+----+----------+
   ```

I mention the second point just in case there is a more efficient way can be applied to achieve both remove operations together. If not, I think I should be able to figure out how to do the second remove once I know how to use the Index information for remove operation. Thanks!

Comment: in your example, the "array" column is not of type array, but of type struct

Comment: You said `the 3rd element (original index before any removal) in the row with id=7 should be removed` so isn't `| 7| CS| 0|[0.4]` supposed to be `| 7| CS| 0|[0.2]`? If thats true then I have answered below that meets your requirement

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have *initial dataframe* as

```
+---+----+----+--------------------+
| id|dept|test|               array|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|
+---+----+----+--------------------+

root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- dept: string (nullable = true)
 |-- test: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = false)
```

You can apply window function to get the row number as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val w = Window.partitionBy("dept").orderBy("id")

val tempdf = df.withColumn("Index", row_number().over(w))
```

which would give you

```
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
|id |dept|test|array               |Index|
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
|1  |CS  |0   |[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|1    |
|5  |CS  |1   |[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|2    |
|7  |CS  |0   |[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|3    |
|101|CS  |1   |[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|4    |
|4  |Ed  |0   |[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|1    |
+---+----+----+--------------------+-----+
```

Next step would be *select rows with dept = CS and test = 1 and get the index list*

```
val csStudentIdIdxToRemove = tempdf.filter("dept = 'CS' and test = '1'").select(collect_list(tempdf("Index"))).collect()(0).getAs[Seq[Int]](0)
//WrappedArray(2, 4)
```

Then you define a udf function to remove the elements from the array column using all of your logic as

```
def removeUdf = udf((array: Seq[Double], additionalIndex: Int) => additionalIndex match{
  case 0 => array.zipWithIndex.filterNot(x => csStudentIdIdxToRemove.contains(x._2 + 1)).map(_._1)
  case _ => {
    val withAdditionalIndex = csStudentIdIdxToRemove ++ Seq(additionalIndex)
    array.zipWithIndex.filterNot(x => withAdditionalIndex.contains(x._2 + 1)).map(_._1)
  }
})
```

and then *call the udf function and drop the Index column*

```
tempdf.withColumn("array", removeUdf(tempdf("array"), when(tempdf("dept") === "CS" && tempdf("test") === 0, tempdf("Index")).otherwise(lit(0))))
    .drop("Index")
```

Finally you should have your desired result

```
+---+----+----+----------+
|1  |CS  |0   |[0.4]     |
|5  |CS  |1   |[0.4, 0.6]|
|7  |CS  |0   |[0.2]     |
|101|CS  |1   |[0.5, 0.3]|
|4  |Ed  |0   |[0.4, 0.3]|
+---+----+----+----------+
```

I hope the answer is concise and helpful

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, I got a not serializable error on the last line of code: Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException
Message: Task not serializable ..... Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec. The error seems to be related to the Window function. I am using Spark 2.3 in standalone mode.

Comment: add `@transient ` as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334595/5880706

Comment: Thanks. It does run after adding @transient before the Window function. I am not very familiar with this. Any performance/resource requirement implication for adding this? Some point to any reference that I can read more about this will be very helpful.

Comment: @transient annotation simply means that the object is not for serialization. You can find more info https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/annotations.html and https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/SCALA/Transient+field+in+non-serializable+class

Comment: @GuanghuaShu if the answer helped you solve your issue then you should consider upvoting and accepting :)

Answer (score 1):

here my solution. To drop the indices, I would use an UDF:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "CS", 0, Seq(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)),
  (4, "Ed", 0, Seq(0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6)),
  (7, "CS", 0, Seq(0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7)),
  (101, "CS", 1, Seq(0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8)),
  (5, "CS", 1, Seq(0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9))
).toDF("id", "dept", "test", "array")


val dropElements = udf(
  (array: Seq[Double], indices: Seq[Int]) =>
    array.zipWithIndex.filterNot { case (x, i) => indices.contains(i + 1) }.map(_._1)
)

df
  .withColumn("index_to_drop", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"dept").orderBy($"id")))
  .withColumn("index_to_drop", when($"test" === 1, $"index_to_drop"))
  .withColumn("indices_to_drop", collect_list($"index_to_drop").over(Window.partitionBy($"dept")))
  .withColumn("array", dropElements($"array", $"indices_to_drop"))
  .select($"id", $"dept", $"test", $"array")
  .show()


+---+----+----+--------------------+
| id|dept|test|               array|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
|  1|  CS|   0|          [0.1, 0.4]|
|  5|  CS|   1|          [0.4, 0.6]|
|  7|  CS|   0|          [0.2, 0.4]|
|101|  CS|   1|          [0.5, 0.3]|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a nice solution with udf. I have two follow ups with your solution: 1) is it also possible to remove corresponding element for dept=Ed? 2) As I mentioned in the last part about the real final result, since some of the elements has been removed, I now cannot know the original index of the element and it is actually not straight forward for second removal. Do you see an efficient way of combing two removal operations together?

Answer (score 1):

This is a different solution without UDF. I would advise you to avoid UDF's as much as you can. The posexplode function is available from spark 2.1.0. Also did not add comments sorry.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.posexplode
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq((1, "CS", 0, Array(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5)), 
             (4, "Ed", 0, Array(0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6)),
             (7, "CS", 0, Array(0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7)),
             (101, "CS", 1, Array(0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8)),
             (5, "CS", 1, Array(0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9)))
             .toDF("id", "dept", "test", "arraytoprocess")

scala> df.show()
+---+----+----+--------------------+
| id|dept|test|      arraytoprocess|
+---+----+----+--------------------+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|
+---+----+----+--------------------+

val columnIndicestoDrop = df.withColumn("zipRank",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("dept")
    .orderBy("id")))
    .withColumn("pos",when($"test" === 1, $"zipRank"-1))
    .filter('pos.isNotNull)
    .select('pos)
    .distinct()

scala> columnIndicestoDrop.show()
+---+
|pos|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
+---+

val dfwitharrayIndices = df.select('id,
    'dept,
    'test,
    'arraytoprocess,
    posexplode($"arraytoprocess") as Seq("pos", "val"))

scala> dfwitharrayIndices.show()
+---+----+----+--------------------+---+---+
| id|dept|test|      arraytoprocess|pos|val|
+---+----+----+--------------------+---+---+
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|  0|0.1|
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|  1|0.2|
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|  2|0.4|
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5]|  3|0.5|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|  0|0.4|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|  1|0.8|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|  2|0.3|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 0.6]|  3|0.6|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|  0|0.2|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|  1|0.5|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|  2|0.4|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.7]|  3|0.7|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|  0|0.5|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|  1|0.7|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|  2|0.3|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.8]|  3|0.8|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|  0|0.4|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|  1|0.2|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|  2|0.6|
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.2, 0.6, 0.9]|  3|0.9|
+---+----+----+--------------------+---+---+

val finaldataFrame = dfwitharrayIndices
    .join(broadcast(columnIndicestoDrop),Seq("pos"),"leftanti")
    .select('id,'dept,'test,'val)
    .groupBy('id,'dept,'test)
    .agg(collect_list('val).as("finalarray"))

scala> finaldataFrame.show()
+---+----+----+----------+
| id|dept|test|finalarray|
+---+----+----+----------+
|  5|  CS|   1|[0.4, 0.6]|
|  4|  Ed|   0|[0.4, 0.3]|
|  1|  CS|   0|[0.1, 0.4]|
|  7|  CS|   0|[0.2, 0.4]|
|101|  CS|   1|[0.5, 0.3]|
+---+----+----+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay, can you give some insight on why do you prefer posexplode over udf? It seems that posexplode could be expensive when the dataFrame is large.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of this. But I feel the udf is doing string comparision which triggers spark to convert all your string to java.lang.string which is an expensive process as java strings take up lot of your space. But with posexplode you are not doing any string manipulation rather we are just joining two dataframes/datasets which is something spark is really good at. But let me know how the above code scales. And its always good to avoid udf's as spark functions are always efficient.